# Varnish not purging quickly/correctly

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, varnish

I'm setting up a Varnish server in front of a Joomla site via Apache/MySQL. I've gotten Varnish to work with Apache and here the Varnish config:

```
acl purge {
    "localhost";
}


backend apache {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8090";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.url ~ "^/administrator" ||
        req.url ~ "^/component/banners" ||
        req.request == "POST") {
            return (pass);
    }

    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }

    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
        # unkown algorithm
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    remove req.http.X_Forwarded-For;
    set req.http.X-Forwareded-For = client.ip;

    unset req.http.Cookie;

    set req.grace = 1h;

    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.grace = 1h;

    set beresp.ttl = 60s;
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}
```

So here is my problem: When I create a new article/update an article, and I purge the cache manual for the home page, it's not purging it and updating the cache with the new article/update.

Any suggestions?

Also, any suggestions/additions/subtractions from my current Varnish config?

Comment: How do you send a purge request I mean using CURL or something? What response do you get in response to a purge request?